# How to keep the previous position when expand and collapse group with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, layout, grouping, expand, cytoscape.js

I've been searching for a good topology layout javascript library for a long time. I learned many library [D3](https://d3js.org/), [WebCola](https://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/), and so on, and eventually I was deeply attracted to 
[cytoscape](http://js.cytoscape.org) and its amazing extension [cytoscape.js-expand-collapse](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse)

What I want is a javascript layout library, which can do a reasonable layout with a lot of nodes. The parent nodes contains children nodes, in other words, there is an inheritance relationship between the nodes.

[This Demo](https://rawgit.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse/master/demo.html) is almost extactly what I need. The expanding and collapsing feature is really great.

And I create my demo base on the above demo. But, when expand a node and then collapse the node, all nodes on the graph are changed.

Initial graph

[image]

The state after expand and collapse node at first time

[image]

The state after expand and collapse node at second time

[image]

Obviously that's not my need. And I learn the original offial demo again. I find the `elements` values of demo has `position` on each data.

```
{"data":{"id":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c"},"position":{"x":577.5410894097904,"y":612.5647477282114},"group":"nodes"}
```

I know if each data has reasonable coordinate, all nodes position will not be changed after expand and collapse some nodes.

The key point is that I don't know the coordinate and I can't set the initial coordinate for my nodes. I think the core algorithm of layout is to calculate the appropriate coordinate points for each point.

So, I can't set the initial coordinate for all nodes and I expect all nodes position are fixed , no matter expand and collpase any node. Is it possible?

The following is my demo.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    ready: function() {
      var api = this.expandCollapse({
        layoutBy: {
          name: "cose-bilkent",
          animate: "end",
          randomize: false,
          fit: false
        },
        fisheye: true,
        animate: false,
        undoable: false
      });
      api.collapseAll();
    },

    style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    }],

    elements: [{
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "n_0",
        "name": "External Network"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "n_4",
        "name": "虚拟机网络",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "n_3",
        "name": "VM Network 2",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_128",
        "name": "bfcui-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_105",
        "name": "bychen-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_93",
        "name": "CE-bj",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_100",
        "name": "changliu-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_67",
        "name": "chaoma-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_83",
        "name": "chenwang",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_68",
        "name": "cwang-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_15",
        "name": "gqpei-bj",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_1",
        "name": "gwxu-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_118",
        "name": "gyzhao-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_76",
        "name": "hlli-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_18",
        "name": "hwzhang-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_40",
        "name": "hxqu-pc"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_69",
        "name": "hxwang-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_71",
        "name": "jbshi-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_64",
        "name": "jdai-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_16",
        "name": "jfxiao-bj",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_78",
        "name": "jhhou-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_91",
        "name": "jjsun-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_17",
        "name": "jppan-bj",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_45",
        "name": "jqwang-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_50",
        "name": "jxli-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_42",
        "name": "jyyou-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_28",
        "name": "jyzhou-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_46",
        "name": "jzhao-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_19",
        "name": "lfeng-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_65",
        "name": "lhzhen-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_1",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_1"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_100",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_100"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_46",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_64",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_64"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_65",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_65"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_67",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_67"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_69",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_69"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_71",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_71"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_76",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_76"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_78",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_78"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_83",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_83"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_91",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_91"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_1n_0",
        "source": "v_1",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_1v_128",
        "source": "v_1",
        "target": "v_128"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_100n_0",
        "source": "v_100",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_16",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_16"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_18",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_18"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_46",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_67",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_67"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_69",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_69"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_71",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_71"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_78",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_78"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128n_0",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_1",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_1"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_105",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_105"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_46",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_65",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_65"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_15n_0",
        "source": "v_15",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_50v_40",
        "source": "v_50",
        "target": "v_40"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_50v_46",
        "source": "v_50",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_50v_64",
        "source": "v_50",
        "target": "v_64"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_65v_19",
        "source": "v_65",
        "target": "v_19"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_65v_91",
        "source": "v_65",
        "target": "v_91"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67n_0",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67v_100",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "v_100"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67v_105",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "v_105"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67v_42",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "v_42"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_16",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_16"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_18",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_18"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_28",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_28"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_45",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_45"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "group2"
      }
    }]
  });
  var api = cy.expandCollapse('get');
  var beforeExpand = null;
cy.unbind('expandcollapse.beforeexpand');
cy.nodes().bind('expandcollapse.beforeexpand', function(event) { 
   if (beforeExpand == null) 
      beforeExpand = cy.elements().clone();  // save the graph before the first expand
}); // Triggered before a node is expanded

cy.unbind('expandcollapse.aftercollapse');
cy.nodes().bind('expandcollapse.aftercollapse', function(event) { 
   if(beforeExpand != null) {
       cy.elements().remove();
       cy.add(beforeExpand);  // set the graph to original values
       beforeExpand = null;
   }
}); 
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.1.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
<!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.0.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-expand-collapse@3.1.1/cytoscape-expand-collapse.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Finally, sum up what I need :

1. Init graph with some nodes, which may be expandable depending on a property like type. Nodes with type=1 are expandable and type=2 not.
2. All nodes do a reasonable layout, like layoutBy:{name:'cose-bilkent'}
3. When expand one node (eg : A), Send ajax request to get children nodes (eg: A1, A2, A3) and then layout children. The graph maybe need an appropriate adjustments. I hope it's a incremental layout, not a full re-layout.
4. When collapse the previous compond nodes (group A with A1,A2,A3), all nodes on the graph keep the previous position.
5. When expand the last group node (eg : A), the children nodes are also keep the previous position.

I think my requirement is very basic, but I can't find a demo to display this feature? Do I describe my requirement clearly ?

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this exactly? I don't seem to get it, it is "just" a node with the same groups inside but with a different position in the graph, right?

Comment: Thank you for focus this issue again. You can see the three pictures on my post. Assume that at initial state, there are three nodes like A(0, 0), B(150, 0), C(100, 100). When open node A, A display as compond nodes like A1,A2,A3 with eligible position. Then collapse group A, there are still three nodes on graph. But currently, the positions of A,B,C will be changed. I expect they can keep the previous position A(0, 0), B(150, 0), C(100, 100).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, the question is clearer now, I think i have a simpel solution for this feature by using the clone function, which is kind of cheating and probably not the intention of the function, but hey it is what it is :D. When you test this, please be sure to comment if it worked out or if you need help with something. Thx

Comment: @StephanT. I have appended your code into my demo. But there seems to be no obvious effect. I recently learned that what I need maybe an incremental layout, and is learning how to do a incremental layout. If you can let you code work well on my demo, I would like to give you my 50 reputation as a bounty.

Comment: The problem is the demo itself unfortunately, the layout is really weired and the graph pans out of sight at any given time, you'll have to work out a functional demo for me to help you, because the code is really not wrong...

Comment: My demo layout really looks weired, but I also don't why. The demo data is the real data in the production environment. Is it `cytoscape.js` only suitable for simple data layout ?

Comment: It seems, that you have way too many edges for the given amount of nodes and their placement, cytoscape can handle it, but it doesn't look pretty. Please consider making a more reasonable graph out of this, i.e. removing useless edges, maybe connect parents instead?

Comment: I have removed some edges randomly for demo. However, no edge is useless, I can't remove any in production environment.

Comment: I edited my answer, now your demo works with that code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not really efficient. You said yourself, that you don't know the coordinates of your nodes, so cytoscape doesn'know that either. But non the less, cose-blikent still positions the elements as good as possible. The position may change, but the structure stays the same. There is really no problem there that justifies the trouble and work you'd have to go through to.

If you really want to achieve this, i suppose you can do this within a specific event that has occured:

### Code:

```
var nodes = cy.nodes();
var positions = [];
for (node in nodes) {
    positions[node] = nodes[node].position(); // save the i'th nodes positions
}
```

and then after you collapse a parent and expand it again, you can set all the nodes positions that you stored before:

```
var nodes = cy.nodes();
for (node in nodes) {
    nodes[node].position(positions[node]); // set x and y of node
}
```

### Events:

```
cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforecollapse", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) // Triggered before a node is collapsed

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.aftercollapse", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) // Triggered after a node is collapsed

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforeexpand", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) // Triggered before a node is expanded

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.afterexpand", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) // Triggered after a node is expanded
```

### **Edit:**

```
var beforeExpand = null;
cy.unbind('expandcollapse.beforeexpand');
cy.nodes().bind('expandcollapse.beforeexpand', function(event) { 
   if (beforeExpand == null) 
      beforeExpand = cy.elements().clone();  // save the graph before the first expand
}); // Triggered before a node is expanded

cy.unbind('expandcollapse.aftercollapse');
cy.nodes().bind('expandcollapse.aftercollapse', function(event) { 
   if(beforeExpand != null) {
       cy.elements().remove();
       cy.add(beforeExpand);  // set the graph to original values
       beforeExpand = null;
   }
}); // Triggered before a node is expanded
```

### **Edit:**

Here is how you repair your demo:

- change fit: false to fit: true
- change your css for the cytoscape like in the following snippet

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    ready: function() {
      var api = this.expandCollapse({
        layoutBy: {
          name: "cose-bilkent",
          animate: "end",
          randomize: false,
          fit: true               // set this to true
        },
        fisheye: true,
        animate: false,
        undoable: false
      });
      api.collapseAll();
    },

    style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    }],

    elements: [{
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "n_0",
        "name": "External Network"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "n_4",
        "name": "虚拟机网络",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "n_3",
        "name": "VM Network 2",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_128",
        "name": "bfcui-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_105",
        "name": "bychen-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_93",
        "name": "CE-bj",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_100",
        "name": "changliu-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_67",
        "name": "chaoma-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_83",
        "name": "chenwang",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_68",
        "name": "cwang-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_15",
        "name": "gqpei-bj",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_1",
        "name": "gwxu-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_118",
        "name": "gyzhao-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_76",
        "name": "hlli-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_18",
        "name": "hwzhang-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_40",
        "name": "hxqu-pc"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_69",
        "name": "hxwang-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_71",
        "name": "jbshi-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_64",
        "name": "jdai-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_16",
        "name": "jfxiao-bj",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_78",
        "name": "jhhou-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_91",
        "name": "jjsun-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_17",
        "name": "jppan-bj",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_45",
        "name": "jqwang-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_50",
        "name": "jxli-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_42",
        "name": "jyyou-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_28",
        "name": "jyzhou-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_46",
        "name": "jzhao-pc",
        "parent": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_19",
        "name": "lfeng-pc",
        "parent": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "v_65",
        "name": "lhzhen-pc",
        "parent": "group2"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_1",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_1"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_100",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_100"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_46",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_64",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_64"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_65",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_65"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_67",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_67"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_69",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_69"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_71",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_71"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_76",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_76"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_78",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_78"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_83",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_83"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "n_0v_91",
        "source": "n_0",
        "target": "v_91"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_1n_0",
        "source": "v_1",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_1v_128",
        "source": "v_1",
        "target": "v_128"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_100n_0",
        "source": "v_100",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_16",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_16"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_18",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_18"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_46",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_67",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_67"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_69",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_69"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_71",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_71"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_118v_78",
        "source": "v_118",
        "target": "v_78"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128n_0",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_1",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_1"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_105",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_105"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_46",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_128v_65",
        "source": "v_128",
        "target": "v_65"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_15n_0",
        "source": "v_15",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_50v_40",
        "source": "v_50",
        "target": "v_40"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_50v_46",
        "source": "v_50",
        "target": "v_46"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_50v_64",
        "source": "v_50",
        "target": "v_64"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_65v_19",
        "source": "v_65",
        "target": "v_19"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_65v_91",
        "source": "v_65",
        "target": "v_91"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67n_0",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "n_0"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67v_100",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "v_100"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67v_105",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "v_105"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_67v_42",
        "source": "v_67",
        "target": "v_42"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_16",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_16"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_18",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_18"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_28",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_28"
      }
    }, {
      "data": {
        "group": "edges",
        "id": "v_91v_45",
        "source": "v_91",
        "target": "v_45"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "group0"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "group1"
      }
    }, {
      "group": "nodes",
      "data": {
        "id": "group2"
      }
    }]
  });
  var api = cy.expandCollapse('get');
  var beforeExpand = null;
cy.unbind('expandcollapse.beforeexpand');
cy.nodes().bind('expandcollapse.beforeexpand', function(event) { 
   if (beforeExpand == null) 
      beforeExpand = cy.elements().clone();  // save the graph before the first expand
}); // Triggered before a node is expanded

cy.unbind('expandcollapse.aftercollapse');
cy.nodes().bind('expandcollapse.aftercollapse', function(event) { 
   if(beforeExpand != null) {
       cy.elements().remove();
       cy.add(beforeExpand);  // set the graph to original values
       beforeExpand = null;
   }
}); 
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#cy { /*change your css*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.1.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
<!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.0.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-expand-collapse@3.1.1/cytoscape-expand-collapse.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Comment: If I use `cytoscape.js-expand-collapse` extension, Can I use the code you metioned above? On what event to handler ? Could you show me more details?

Comment: I edited the answer, so that you can see the events you can bind.

Comment: Thank you. I have learned the event handlers, but To record all nodes position is still a hard work to me.
`var positions = []; 
cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforeexpand", function(event) {
 var node = this;
 var nodes = cy.nodes();
 for (node in nodes) {
  if(node == parseInt(node, 10)){
   positions[node] = nodes[node].position(); 
  }
 }
});

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforecollapse", function(event) {
 var nodes = cy.nodes();
 for (node in nodes) {
  if(node == parseInt(node, 10)){
   nodes[node].position(positions[node]);
  }
 }
});`

Comment: Add your code into event handler directly can't resolve my problem. Could you please show me a relatively complete code?

Comment: what do you plan to achieve with the `node == parseInt(node, 10)`?

Comment: You use `for... in` to loop array properties in your snippet. In this way, the `length` property will also be visited. So I use `node == parseInt(node, 10)` to make sure only visit integer indices.

Comment: i edited my answer, test it out and let me know if it works out for you

Comment: Your demo can work, and show me how to save coordinate. I would like accept your answer.

Comment: A few days ago, That is my first time to know and learn cytoscape. I can't describe what I need clearly. Now I think only keeping the previous position is not what I need with in-depth learning and understanding. Take the demo for example, there are 5 nodes on the graph at initial state. When expand node `group0`, the children of `group0` do a reasonable layout , nevertheless other 4 nodes also do a random layout, that's not what I need. I think the other 4 nodes should keep previous position or keep their relative position. Maybe it's so called incremental layout. That really is what I need.

Comment: You really shouldn't do that. These positions are calculated for a reason, the graph has to reposition the other (not expanded) nodes, so that the layout is right, otherwise, the nodes would overlap. Pleas reconsider that approach and stick to the demo I have in **Edit:** without the cy.bind() functionality. Expand-collapse works really well just on it's own. Thanks for hearing me out non the less! Keep working on this with the new snippet!

Comment: Some other libraries like `yfile` can do a perfect incremental  layout . So I think `cytoscape` can also do it. See https://live.yworks.com/demos/complete/hierarchicgrouping/index.html

Comment: That demo is pretty cool! Maybe I didn't quite understand what you were saying, but the yfile demo repositions the nodes accordingy, when the expand/collapse happens, just like cytoscape. But I see the difference there now. Implementing this in cy is a piece of work, but take a look at [this](https://github.com/mo0om/cytoscape-even-parent), it might be what you need. I don' t know if it supports compound parents, so you will have to try that out.

Comment: Your link is a cytoscape tree layout extension. I don't think it's helpful to `cose-bilkent` layout. Since you know the difference between `cytoscape` and `yfile`. Is it possible to do a more reasonable incremental layout like `yfile` shows  with `cose-bilkent`? Is it a reasonable feature for `cy`?

Answer (score 2):

The nodes in the example have positions just because it was exported from another tool.

Each time an expand or a collapse operation is performed, if the `layoutBy` option is set, that layout is applied to the graph. In the example the `layoutBy` option is set to `cose-bilkent`, and that is why the positions change.

I believe you can achieve what you want by setting `layoutBy` to `null`, and `fisheye` to `false`. You can see the other options and their explanations [here](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse#default-options).

P.S: for the initial coordinates, you might consider setting the `layout` option of Cytoscape while [initializing](http://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/specifying-basic-options).

Comment: Currently I only add `ready` function to controll inital layout. I guess the expand and collapse behavior is default. How and where to set `layout` to null ?

Comment: Thank you for you response. I got you meaning , but also don't know how to write the code. Could you please show me a simple demo ?

Answer (score 0):

I too, ran into the same issue while using fCose layout, I had forgotten to give the key , "randomize" and set it to false, a simple mistake.
From the docs, it looks it shall randomize the only the overall layout if given true but under the expand-collapse context, it rearranges every single node displayed.

If you also missed on understanding randomize while using different third-party libs, this answer shall help you.